# Looping main and Sub-folder in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, walk, indexerror

I am writing a Python script, which can literate through all main folder and Subfolder. My main folder names are 2001, 2002.....and under main folder differents subfolder is there, Subfolder name : JANUARY, FEBRAURY so on, 
So my existing script I can iterate all subfolder under one main folder, but I can't iterate through all the main and subfolder at the same time, 
Below is my script:

Folder and subfolder structure like this: 
[image]

```
import arcpy, os, calendar
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
topWorkspace = r'D:\Workspace\2006'
env.workspace = topWorkspace
months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)} 

 # Step through list of all folders
for folderPath in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
    baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
    if baseName in months: # Test that subfolder is a month name
        monthNumber = months[baseName] # Get month-number for use in output filename
    arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath

    #Loop every month folder ta take shape file from each month 
    shapeFile = (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('rain_*.shp')[0])
```

I have updated the code using arcpy.da.walk but its producing error

```
    import arcpy, os, calendar
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    topWorkspace = r'D:\Workspace\2006'
    env.workspace = topWorkspace
    months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)} 
    # Get list of all folders 
   walk = arcpy.da.Walk(topWorkspace, topdown=True,datatype="FeatureClass")
     # Step through list of all folders
    for folderPath, folderNames, fileNames in walk:
        baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
        if baseName in months: # Test that subfolder is a month name
            monthNumber = months[baseName] # Get month-number for use in output filename
        arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath

        #Loop every month folder ta take shape file from each month 
        shapeFile = (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('rain_*.shp')[0])
```

Error message:

```
File "<module2>", line 27, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How to address here two  loop condition for main and sub folder

Comment: use the [arcpy.da.Walk()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) function

Comment: I am getting confused Which one first i have to consider Main folder or Subfolder ?

Comment: A nested looping structure ***always*** requires the parents to be in the outer loop. You haven't attempted an inner loop.

Comment: You're looking for shapefiles here, so instead of using `"RasterDataset"` as datatype in your walk function, use `"FeatureClass"`

Comment: You now have two questions in one Question. Please choose one solution or the other.

Comment: Mistakenly i put there Raster data, i have corrected that, but same error massage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your script should look like. Make sure you understand the 3 items in the tuple returned by the [Walk](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) function:

- dirpath is **the path** to the workspace as a string.
- dirnames is **a list of names** of **subdirectories** and other workspaces in dirpath.
- filenames is a **list of names** of **nonworkspace contents** (i.e., files) in dirpath.

  ```
  import arcpy, os, calendar
  from arcpy import env
  from arcpy.sa import *

  topWorkspace = r"D:\Workspace"
  env.workspace = topWorkspace
  months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)}
  # Get list of all folders
  walk = arcpy.da.Walk(topWorkspace, topdown=True, datatype="FeatureClass")
   # Step through list of all folders
  for folderPath, folderNames, fileNames in walk:
      for folderName in folderNames:
          if folderName in months:
              env.workspace = os.path.join(folderPath, folderName)
              if len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('rain_*.shp')) > 0:
                  shapeFile = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('rain_*.shp')[0]
                  ## then do something with each shapefile, e.g. here copy it to another location
                  arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shapeFile, os.path.join(r"C:\Temp", shapeFile[:-4] + "_copy.shp"))
  ```